# extract substring doesn't work on lookup field -sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

When I try to extract a substring from a lookup field in list I don't get nothing (using a workflow) when I use nonlookup field it works. 
Any idea of how to fix this. what I am missing.

Comment: The lookup field does not store the lookup value as such. Instead it stored it as LookupId;#LookupValue. Can you relate your problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the class SPFieldLookupValue.

You can use the two properties LookupValue and LookupId to extract values from the field, there is no other need to extract the substring.

```
SPFieldLookupValue lookup = new SPFieldLookupValue(item["fieldName"] as string);
        lookup.LookupValue;
        lookup.LookupId;
```

Hope this helps.